# Split function of c# by space is splitting string character wise

Tags: c#

I am new to WPF.

In my application, I want to split a string by space.

code:

```
string str="Hi I am a string";
string[] strList=str.Split(' ');
MessageBox.show("Length: "+ strList.Length); //output: Length: 16
```

I also tried

```
string str="Hi I am a string";
char[] splitchar = { ' ' };
string[] strList=str.Split(splitchar);
MessageBox.show("Length: "+ strList.Length); //output: Length: 16
```

I also tried

```
string str="Hi I am a string";
string[] strList=str.Split();
MessageBox.show("Length: "+ strList.Length); //output: Length: 16
```

But in all of the cases, it is printing length: 16. It should print 5

If I print the values of strList then it is printing h i i a m a s t r i n g

Please guide me.

Comment: Which character set you are using in your project?

Comment: it works : https://dotnetfiddle.net/CJtVF4

Comment: Apperently, you have a white space char between your letters.

Comment: Apart from the fact, that the method is called `.Split()` and not `.split()`, your code should work as intended.

Comment: I copy & pasted your code and it works as expected. In your real code, did you not accidentally print `str.Length`? That would explain why you get `16`...

Comment: Try removing the space you're splitting by and reinserting it, if you have something which in your IDE or editor looks like a space but is actually something else then Split may behave weirdly.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

> just do  like this

you are using `.split()` but it is `.Split()`

```
public static void Main()
    {
        string str="Hi I am a string";
        string[] strList=str.Split(' ');
        Console.WriteLine("Length"+" "+strList.Length);
    }
```

> output is 5

Comment: OP, why have you accepted this answer? This is the same as your first code example (except the corrected typo).

Comment: `.split()` doesn't exist. If OP was using `.split()` you would get a compile-time failure, not a working program with an unexpected output. [Example](http://rextester.com/WJYEAZ73616)

Comment: john why u are going mad man look closely its .Split() not .split()

Comment: `.split(' ')` with a lowercase S seems like a clear typo in the question, which means your answer being the solution doesn't make any sense. I'm not "going mad man". I'm talking sense.

Comment: @ArunPratap - John's doing so because the answer doesn't make sense. Pixel, this can't be the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Well, I don't know. Either they have their own string extension method called `split`, which would explain why your solution works, or they've mistakenly accepted your answer. As it stands, it's unclear. Though if they had an extension method called `split`, I'd hope they would realise that.

Comment: @ArunPratap - I don't think you can remove it now that it's been accepted.

Comment: ok @Enigmativity thanks but i think we can also flag questions?